# How to fix strongswan VPN on Android build errors?

Tags: android, vpn, strongswan

I'm trying to build Strongswan on android (https://github.com/strongswan/strongswan/tree/master/src/frontends/android).
I follow the instructions (https://docs.strongswan.org/docs/5.9/os/androidVpnClientBuild.html) and create OpenSSL using the command:

`ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=~/android-ndk-<ver> \ OPENSSL_SRC=~/openssl-<ver> \ src/frontends/android/openssl/build.sh`

I get success message, however it is followed by errors and openssl folder in /Users/mac/strongswan/src/frontends/android/app/src/main/jni/openssl  is empty:
[image]

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: It is complaining about not finding Python in `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: I use sudo ln -s /Users/mac/.pyenv/versions/2.7.18/bin/python /usr/bin/python but permission denied. I disable csr and run sudo mount -uw / but get - mount_apfs: volume could not be mounted: Permission denied
mount: / failed with 66
How can I solve it?